# Why was my answer removed?

Tags: discussion

I wrote an answer to the question [Why doesn't Lichess' Stockfish suggest this bishop sacrifice?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/29834/why-doesnt-lichess-stockfish-suggest-this-bishop-sacrifice/29844#29844) where I offered a different perspective on how to interpret the output of an engine when the advantage is too big. It was removed for some reason

Answer (score 2):

It was flagged for not being an answer. If you feel strongly then post it as a comment on the main question but don't post comments as answers.

Comment: What I find odd is that, had I written a twenty-line answer that said the exact same thing but with fancier wording, it would have probably stayed

Comment: I disagree that it's not an answer. It answers the question very directly: SF doesn't suggest the sacrifice because everything else wins more (because everything wins).